# How to set a global click option that would be used as a base for different click options and that can be overriden by the user at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

Hy'all, I'm using [python click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) to develop a cli.
I have the following situation:

First I have a config file in `config.py`, where I store re-usable variables across my project

```
# config.py

class Config:
    base_path = "/home/project/"
```

Then, I have a cli command in `command.py`, where I'm using the path config variable

```
# command.py
import click
from config import Config

@click.command()
@click.option('--path', show_default=True, default=f"{Config.base_path}/some/another_path.json")
def some_command(path):
    """ command example"""
    print(f"my path is: {path}")
```

And finally, I have my parent cli or my entry point

```
import click
from config import Config
from command import some_command

@click.group()
@click.option('--base-path', show_default=True, default=Config.base_path)
@pass_context
def cli(ctx, base_path):
    """ entry point"""
    ctx.obj = {"base_path": base_path}

cli.add_command(some_command)
```

So as you can see, I have a global config variable that I want users to be able to override through the cli

For example, by running `$ cli --base-path ~/custom/path some_command`, I want the `--path` option for the some_command to be overriden to `~/custom/path/some/another_path.json` as well since it is based on it.

However, that is not what is happening because the --base-path would be overriden by the user at runtime and therefore the changes are not reflected. So my question is what is the best way to solve this problem?

I tried to override the `Config.base_path` var like this:

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--base-path', show_default=True, default=Config.base_path)
@pass_context
def cli(ctx, base_path):
    """ entry point"""
    Config.base_path = base_path
    ctx.obj = {"base_path": base_path}
```

Obviously that did not work because the variable was overriden in the context, which is after being set in the `some_command` command already.

Any ideas? thanks in advance